# How to disable resizing of columns in a TornadoFx tableview?

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

I have a few columns in a tableview, and would like their widths to stay constant when the view expands. This seems quite simple with `maxWidth = minWidth = 120.px`. My problem is I would also like to completely disable the resizing of the columns by the user. This is what I have so far:

```
tableview(model) {
    smartResize()
    column("DATE", Model::date) {
        isResizable = true // This is where it seems to work
        style {
            minWidth = 120.px
            prefWidth = 120.px
        }
        cellFormat {
            graphic = cache(rowItem.id) {
                datepicker(rowItem.dateProperty) {
                    style {
                        textAlignment = TextAlignment.CENTER
                            maxWidth = 200.px
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    column("LAME/\nWCO", RWADetail::lameWco).makeEditable().style {
        alignment = Pos.CENTER
    }
    column("DESCRIPTION", RWADetail::description).makeEditable().remainingWidth().style {
        alignment = Pos.CENTER_LEFT
    }
}
```

However this leads to strange result where the empty rows below have different widths. 
This is a snip of the resulting date column with inconsistent sizing for the empty rows:

[image]

Am I on the right track?

Comment: What do you mean by strange results? Can you post a runnable code sample as well as a screenshot?

Comment: I'm not sure how to embed a screenshot without uploading to a website so here is the image on my google drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n7OexmLgyHWxDyuwWxIPS0OfZCdHRg4s/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You can actually just paste the image here and SO will upload to Imgur automatically. I've seen these issues often, you might need to manually refresh the tableview. Post a runnable code sample so we can investigate.

Comment: Oh ok, I shall try it out. I will post a runnable sample as soon as I can.

Comment: I'm not sure how much code you meant by runnable code, but I have added an image of the result and added code for my whole table. All the style I use is embedded here.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I answered my own question: the trick was the TornadoFx method called `fixedWidth(200)`. Below is my modified code

```
tableview(model) {
    smartResize()
    column("DATE", Model::date) {
        style {
            fixedWidth(120)
        }
        cellFormat {
            graphic = cache(rowItem.id) {
                datepicker(rowItem.dateProperty) 
            }
        }
    }
    column("LAME/\nWCO", RWADetail::lameWco).makeEditable().style {
        fixedWidth(120)
        alignment = Pos.CENTER
    }
    column("DESCRIPTION", RWADetail::description).makeEditable().remainingWidth().style {
        fixedWidth(120)
        alignment = Pos.CENTER_LEFT
    }
}
```